# Initialize docker volume ony once

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to initialize a docker volume only after it has been created, not each time a container is created or built.

For example lets say I want to store the content of a database in the volume. At the creation of the volume I would like to create the database schema, but once this schema exists I don't want to create it again since it could cause some unwanted side effects.

Right now one of the solution I see is to create a flag in the volume once it has been initialized and in later calls check if this flag exists before performing the initialization.

I just wanted to know if docker has a native way of achieving it.

Comment: did you try to store your DB on your hostmachine and include it to docker? works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom image that gets built with database schema created with database's data directory stored into a docker volume. Later on use that image to create/run containers.